# Unable to forward X11 graphics from Centos on Vagrant

Tags: ssh, xorg, virtualization, vagrant, x11-forwarding

On my real machine (`Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`) I deployed a Vagrant virtual machine and tried to forward X11 graphics from VM to real machine.

For this I added in **Vagrantfile** such configurations:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    i = 1
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
    ...
```

For accessing to my VM I used `vagrant ssh -- -X` or `vagrant ssh -- -Y`.
But if I try to open any graphical application in VM, I get an error:

```
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

How can I fix this problem?

If it matters, the OS on my virtual machine isn't Ubuntu:

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

Comment: Do you have installed "X Window System" on CentOS? `yum groupinstall "X Window System"`.

Comment: @Jakuje, thanks a lot! I have just installed these packages and now graphics is working. Do you want to post your advice as answer and got +15? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have installed all the required packages on the CentOS machine. You can do that simply by installing whole group for X system:

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```